# Using shell script i want to give space to the starting of every line of a file

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

i want to write a shell script and in that shell script i want to give space to the starting of every line of a file like, 1st line 1 space, 2nd line 2 sapce, 3rd line 3 space, 4th line 4 space......
output will be like
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
for x in {1..6}; do printf "%${x}s\n" $x ; done
```